# error when using 'file' function in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, storage

i have a text file in the storage/app folder and i wanna use php file() function in the controller but get me an error :

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I'm using laravel 5.5

Comment: write down your code, so someone may help. You probably have incorrect path. storage/app is default folder for laravel's file system, not php.

Comment: You should not do that. Laravel has a [file abstraction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#retrieving-files) you should use instead. That way if in future you need to switch to a remote filesystem such as S3 you can do so easily.

Comment: yes, i used this method instead
but i don't know yet why that method doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

I think you should give permission to your storage folder.It is permission issue.

Run this command in your project folder:

`sudo chmod 777 -R storage/`

You should also check that you are using file package in your controller.

Comment: Laravel won't work at all if there is a permission issue with storage folder.